# Regarding scikit_learn installation

Tags: docker, scikit-learn, buildx

Hello and thank you for looking at this.  I have been using docker to create various multi-arch builds.  I have noticed some interesting behavior.  When trying to run buildx for image creation, scikit_learn 0.21.3 takes a very long time to download/install (about 2.5 hours).  However, when using the regular build command through docker on a single arch, it only takes about 10 minutes or so.  The reason I am having to use this specific version of scikit_learn is due to an error I receive from my application where it is unable to find the sklearn.utils.linear_assignment module.
I receive this `\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.utils.linear_assignment_'`
The only version I have been able to run is 0.21.3 up to this point.  Having said that, I have found more recent versions do install much faster, but again they do not have the linear assigmment module, which is a dependency for my application.  Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just realized I was pulling 0.23.1 instead of 0.21.3 in my buildx dockerfile, which shows me I was wrong.  sorry about that.  However, I would still like to know if there is a way to use more recent versions without getting the error I was receiving.  Thanks again

Comment: Update:  buildx still taking a very long time in comparison wit normal build command.  0.21.3 is so far at around 2,000 seconds and still building the wheel

Comment: Complete wheel build time for scikit was 4953 seconds using docker buildx command using ubuntu 20.04 .  Building directly on a device was around 10 minutes using only the docker build command.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.